# datetimepicker not working in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, nuget, razor-pages

I was trying to use a DateTimePicker in the Asp.net core Razor page.
I searched the internet and found [this page](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) seems works good.
So, I went to the NuPackage and found Bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker 4.17.45, and downloaded it.
After install, I got a warning:

**Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker 4.17.45 depends on bootstrap.less (>= 3.3.0) but bootstrap.less 3.3.0 was not found. An approximate best match of bootstrap.less 3.3.5 was resolved.**

Since the bootstrap version in the project is 3.3.5, and it is a warning instead an error, so I think it should be fine. I copied the sample code into my cshtml file, and run it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The DateTimePicker showed up. How ever, when I clicked on the calendar button, nothing happened. It seems javascript is not running?

I searched everywhere, and I found this part in the layout page.

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

It seems I need to include the js file which contains the datetimepicker here. However, I search the whole project, cannot find any js file contains 'datetimepicker' string.

I am not familiar with front-end structure. what I did wrong or missing? Is my datetimepicker installation not success? is the js script not working on my razor page? How do I diagnose it?

Added:
I enabled the javascript debugging, and I got the following exception. It looks really wired as exception comes from the sample code, which runs with no problem on the original webpage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTimePicker.js NuGet package itself will be in the `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages` directory if you need to get the javascript files.You could copy it in your project and add `@section Scripts {` and `}` in your project.

The better way is to use either [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-library-files) or npm to get your client-side libraries.

Here is a simple sample in my project as below.Anyway,the version up to you:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/3.3.0/content/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/3.3.0/content/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/1.9.1/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/moment.js/2.9.0/Content/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/3.3.0/content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker/4.17.45/content/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note**: `moment.js` should render before the `datetimepicker.js`

Comment: It took me couple of hours and finally made it work yesterday, It was too late and also my solution is not that elegant so I think I will just keep the question open for a good solution. Don't know why - after the installation, js files did not copied to my project. I manually copy the js file to my solution, and changed the code exactly as you mentioned. Just made a change on your solution - it is @section Scripts missing. Also, can you please add a little bit more detail on how to install the package? It will benefit other developers.